# Call A Multi-Part Form Method Programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, post, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I have the following method in my WebApi

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("foo/bar")]
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
[DisableRequestSizeLimit]
public async Task<IActionResult> FooBar([FromForm] Data data)
```

The Data class looks like this

```
public class Data
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string[] B { get; set; }
    public string[] C { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

I am struggling to work out how I can pass the values in the Data class into this method via C# code. I need to pass the string A, the two string arrays B and C and the file File.  I can easily do this via Swagger but not through code.  I have the URL to the api so that's not an issue.  The only problem is knowing what code to write here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `HttpClient` and send `MultipartFormDataContent` in controller

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        content.Add(new StringContent("testA"), "A");//string
        content.Add(new StringContent("testB"), "B");
        content.Add(new StringContent("testBB"), "B");//string[]
        content.Add(new StringContent("testC"), "C");
        content.Add(new StringContent("testCC"), "C");
        
        //replace with your own file path, below use an image in wwwroot for example
        string filePath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + "\\Images", "myImage.PNG");

        byte[] file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
                
        var byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(file);

        content.Add(byteArrayContent, "file", "myfile.PNG");
        
        var url = "https://locahhost:5001/foo/bar";
        var result = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
    }
}
```

Comment: what about if If you have this scenario:
API => api client => 3rdparty.. how the Ifile should be handled in the api client?