# File Uploading using HttpClient in .Net core 3.0 Console Application

Tags: asp.net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.0

I am trying to upload file using HttpClient in Asp.net Core 3, but It is not uploading file to the server. If I try to upload file to the server via Postman, it works.

Below is my simple code to upload file:

```
HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
var stream = new FileStream("main.txt", FileMode.Open);
byte[] fileBytes = new byte[stream.Length];
stream.Write(fileBytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);
stream.Dispose();

using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
    var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);
    fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = "Test",
    };
    fileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");
    content.Add(fileContent);

    _client.PostAsync("http://192.168.56.1:8000", content);                
}
```

As I said above it is working with Postman. I am putting a screenshot which shows that how I doing with Postman.

[image]

[image]

when I debug the code, so I get below error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One solution is that you could use `MemoryStream` to transform the content of the file. Your method will cause the content in the main.txt file to become empty.

Change your code like this:

```
HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
Stream stream = new FileStream("main.txt", FileMode.Open);​ 
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();​
stream.CopyTo(ms);​
byte[] fileBytes = ms.ToArray();​
ms.Dispose(); ​
```

Another way is that use `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath)`.

Try to post file using below example code instead, refer to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58645233/call-a-multi-part-form-method-programmatically/58655025#58655025).

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {

                //replace with your own file path, below use an txt in wwwroot for example
                string filePath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "main.txt");

                byte[] file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

                var byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(file);

                content.Add(byteArrayContent, "file", "main.txt");

                var url = "https://localhost:5001/foo/bar";
                var result = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

            }
        }
```

foo/bar action

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("foo/bar")]
public IActionResult ProcessData([FromForm]IFormFile file)
{
     //your logic to upload file
}
```

Comment: Thanks Xing Zou, I tried your example, but the same error is coming which I mentioned in my question. Bascially I have a Console Application which is trying to upload a file to the server.

Comment: I have downloaded miniweb http server from the internet, just to download and upload file from local drive through url.

I have downloaded from here
https://sourceforge.net/projects/miniweb/

Comment: @use3661407 I have no idea. Maybe you need to check your server log.

Comment: there is no any server log. I just downloaded the server from the internet and it is an exe file. I cannot see any log.

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded the server and tested it with this code. The server returns 200 OK

```cs
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
   using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
   {
      using (var fileStream = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Open))
      {
         var fileContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);

          content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
          content.Add(fileContent, "file", "test.txt");

          var response = await client.PostAsync("http://192.168.56.1:8000/", content);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I tried with await before, but nothing happened.  I am unable to find that where I am missing something. I searched on the google every example is presenting the same implementation, which I have put in my question.

Comment: @user3661407, Added one more idea

Comment: Hiw do you upload file with Postman. Can you attach screenshots?

Comment: Anthon, I just updated the question with postman screens shot.

Regarding Error- I am not getting any error. Everything is working fine.

Comment: Please try to get response of request and see status code and message of it `var response = await _client.PostAsync(..);`

Comment: As I updated my question that I am getting exception on _client.PostAsyn(..) line, when I try to debug code and It is saying that "An error occurred while sending the request. The response ended prematurely".

Comment: @user3661407 Hi, I updated my answer. Tested with miniweb

Comment: When I try to run your code. I am getting status in reponse "WaitingForActivation". I am not getting any 200.

Comment: Possibly smth with your server configuration. Which OS do you use? If it is Linux, I'll try to repeat it later

Comment: I am using Windows 10. I am unable to understand that it is working with postman but not with HttpClient in C#.

Comment: How do you run miniweb?

Comment: I just click on the exe file and It starts running

Comment: I have no idea. Maybe I'll try on the weekend

Comment: Thanks I am looking forward to you reply. Do you also know that how I can achieve same behaviour from other http server, If you know.